# Criteria queries in EJB 3

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, criteria

Can I use Criteria queries with EJB3 entities? If so, how can I combine them with EntityManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA doesn't provide a Criteria API like in Hibernate. But you can use [ejb3criteria](http://code.google.com/p/ejb3criteria/), a library that provides an API based on Hibernate Criteria API design for EJB3 Persistence. ejb3criteria can be used with any EJB3 Persistence implementation.

Comment: Tried, yes; used in production, no. This just means I didn't use it heavily, but I'm not saying "don't use it in production".

Answer (score 7):

One of the new features introduced in the JPA 2.0 is the Criteria API.
You need one of the JPA2 implementations:

- [Hibernate 3.5](http://www.hibernate.org/) now has JPA2 support
- [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) (reference JPA2 implementation)
- [Apache OpenJPA 2.0](http://openjpa.apache.org/)

Criteria queries are accessed through the EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(), and executed through the normal Query API.

```
EntityManager em = ...;
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = qb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);
query.where(qb.equal(employee.get("firstName"), "Bob"));
List<Employee> result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: True. But that's not part of JPA 1.0/EJB 3.0 which is what the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2 (providing the criteria API) was defined in JSR 317 which can be regarded as successor to JSR 220 (the original EJB/JPA specification). Hence your comment "True. But that's not part of JPA 1.0/EJB 3.0 which is what the question was about." is irrelevant as you can use JPA 2 interchangeably on all common application servers (WebLogic, JBOSS, Glassfish, etc.) Green field projects will use JPA 2.0 or later. You will find many projects implemented using JPA 1 but most companies are in the process of replacing the JPA 1 framework.